# Why some footnote citations don't find their reference higher in the pdf while others do?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing, footnotes, biber

### Issue

I'm using the following setup for bibliography :

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,autocite=footnote,style=footnote-dw,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{these.bib}
```

So functionning non-first citations of a key look like the screenshot just below, where `(cf. note n)` allows cross-referencing to jump to the first occurence of the citation (this is featured into the biber style I'm using).

[image]

However some citations seem to encounter an issue with the `(cf. note n)` part, giving the following :

[image]

The reference works OK though, as the link embedded into the title (in blue) is clickable and functional, but for some reason the page numer goes wild!

---

### A bit of investigation

I looked into the very first citation of this key but there seems to be no issue there.

I also linted the citation reference inside the `.bib` file to ensure it's not because of special characters `ü` `ö`or `ä` so changing those into `{\"o}` didn't do anything.

Looking up into the log I find the following warning :

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `cbx@618' on page 201 undefined on input line 409.
```

There are 42 warnings like that, each time corresponding to identical situation where the reference is working in the title link but doesn't seem to find the corresponding page.

I don't know if it's connected or not but I found also the following lines in the code which mention another citation of the same cite key :

```
[160]pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{cite.0:Brade1975}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.66 ...l{XII}, d'après \citeN{Brade1975}[p.~71]}
```

fyi >> `\citeN{<key>}[<prenote>]` is just a command of mine

---

### Solved

In the end : as I used biber and footnote citation style the `figure` environment had to be placed inside a `savenotes` environment, otherwise the footnote-citation would not appear in the footer and thus would raise a reference warning because next same citation would not find it.

So, solution is :

```
\begin{savenotes}
\begin{figure}
...
\caption[caption without cite]{caption with cite\footcite{bibkey}}
\end{figure}
\end{savenotes}
```

Comment: footnote links are difficult (and personally I wouldn't use them) and without a small but complete example it is quite impossible to debug this.

Comment: Ulrike definitely knows more about links than me, so I will defer to her on that one, but the output you show does not only show problems with the link, it shows problems with `\label`-`\ref` and that should in theory not be an issue. Unfortunately, this issue cannot be debugged properly without a small example document that reproduces the undesirable behaviour with as little code as possible. I understand that it might seem (and be) a bit of work to turn a large document into a small example, but that really is the only way to ensure you get a good answer ...

Comment: ... see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 for help with coming up with an example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/35864 for background.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , @moewe Okay thanks guys, I'll try to create a MWE if I find some time for it. Worst case scenario I'll see if I can just get rid of the `(cf. note n)` part in the package parameters.

Comment: Any news here? Without a document that reproduces the issue this issue is almost impossible to investigate.

Comment: Hey @moewe thanks for reaching out! I finally managed to debug the file this evening : `LaTeX Warning: Reference cbx@618` was due to occurrences of the bugged citation being placed inside figure's captions which were missing `\begin{savenotes}...\end{savenotes}` around it : the footnote did not appear in the footer and thus following same citation could not find it, therefore `cf. note ??`. I don't know how to mark the post as "solved" though

Comment: Just write an answer in the answers section below and accept it. (And edit the solution out of the question.)